# Using CLIP command within a Batch File

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt, clip

I am trying to write a batch file to do the following:

1. Copy a given file (drag and drop or through "send to" option) to a predefined network drive
2. Build a file path string
3. Copy the file path to the clipboard

Here is what I have so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO "%~1"
ECHO "Uploading File..."
COPY "%~1" "PATH_TO_NETWORK_DRIVE"
SET "path=PATH_TO_NETWORK_DRIVE"
SET "file=%~nx1"
SET "link=%path%%file%"
ECHO %link%> "I:\filepath.txt"
START "I:\filepath.txt"
```

The above works in so far as the file is copied to the correct location and the text file is created containing the path string. I'm only using an external text file and the START command above purely because I've hit a road block in getting the text file to copy to the clipboard, trying numerous variations of the CLIP command. I've tried:

```
ECHO %link%| clip

clip < "I:\filepath.txt"

type "I:\filepath.txt" | clip
```

None of the above are working for me, despite other threads on here suggesting that they should. Is there a limitation in using CLIP in a batch file? Is there any workaround to this? Any assistance I can get would be hugely appreciated :)

Comment: When you say it's not working, what are you expecting and what is actually happening?

Comment: Hi @aphoria - I am expecting that after the batch file runs and closes that I should be able to hit paste in, say, an email and the filepath should be pasted from the clipboard, but this is not happening; either nothing appears or whatever the last thing I copied before running the batch file is pasted :(

Comment: Further to the above; I have tried using the clip command directly from command prompt and it works fine, which is why I'm assuming a limitation with batch files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're wiping out your system `path` with this statement, so your batch file probably can't find `CLIP.EXE`.

```
SET "path=PATH_TO_NETWORK_DRIVE"
```

Change it to `mypath` (or any other name):

```
SET "mypath=PATH_TO_NETWORK_DRIVE"
```

Also, change all of your references from `%path%` to `%mypath%`.

Comment: You beauty, thanks a million; working like a charm now without the need for a text file - just using `ECHO %link%| clip`